# some symbols in URL are changed hex during page loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, url

When I click href, the URL is changed during page load.

I click href, www.test.com/main#/?arg1=1&arg2=2
, then it is displayed in URL bar.
But during page loading URL is suddenly changed to www.test.com/main#!#%2F%3Farg1=1&arg2=2

I am not sure why #/? characters are changed to #!#%2F%3F

This issue has happened since I update Angularjs version.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not able to work with urls with `#` in the middle. Only when `#` is the anchor of the URL.

When .html.erb is loaded, Rails encode this symbols inside the URLs. You can do something like this.

**.html.erb**

```rb
<%= link_to 'angular link','www.test.com/main#/?arg1=1&arg2=2', class: 'angular-link', data: { url: 'www.test.com/main#/?arg1=1&arg2=2' } %>
```

**javascript**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const angularLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('angular-link');
  for(let angularLink of angularLinks) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var angularURL = angularLink.getAttribute('data-url');
      angularLink.setAttribute('href', angularURL);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Is not the best solution, but it works ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was the hashbang of angularjs.
angularjs now requires Exclamation mark.
I puts ! symbol like this and it works.

## !/?